# How can I draw a half painted ellipsis on a canvas?

Tags: delphi, canvas

I know how to draw an ellipsis on a canvas,

But is there any way to draw a half painted ellipsis on the canvas?

Comment: You can clip the canvas.

Comment: Draw an arc or a pie.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`TCanvas.Pie`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Pie) for that. See also, [How do I call the Pie function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3284003/33732)